# Get the item just added to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When a user in my shop adds an item to his cart, he gets redirected to the cart page where a green message shows which item was just added (ajax is disabled).

I want to show different information based on the product that was added, but I can't figure out how to get the id of the product.

I **can't** just use the last item in cart, because that would always show the custom message, even when the product was not just added.

I **can't** use the *wc_add_to_cart_message* filter because I need to show the information *above* the message.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick and dirty solution myself:

```
function wc_add_to_cart_message_filter($message, $product_id = null) {
    $message = 'Extra field.</div><div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">' . $message;
    return $message;
}
add_filter ( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_filter', 10, 2 );
```

I just split the *div* element and create another one above, in which I have access to the product ID.

The rest is then done via CSS and the *:first-child* selector...